# Can a Gradle project inherit multiple parent project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Can a Gradle Project have multiple parent project. I have common project which I want to include as sub project in multiple Gradle project. Is it possible ? In below diagram I have tried explaining it, where b is a common sub-project

I tried including a sub project of some project to other project, and it was unable to locate classes.

```
           -> b
          /
      a ->
     /    \
    /      -> c
z ->
           -> b
          /
      p ->
          \
           -> r
```

Comment: A project can have more than one ancestor (c in your example has a and z).

Answer (score 0):

As per your above model structure neither Maven nor Gradle support multiple inheritance, but you can use as plugin in gradle or import in case of maven dependency management. Others can comment on this.